# Generating code for converting between classes

Tags: java, eclipse, type-conversion

In one of the project I'm working on, we have different systems. 
Since those system should evolve independently we have a number of CommunicationLib to handle communication between those Systems.
CommunicationLib objects are not used inside any System, but only in communication between systems. 
Since many functionality require data retrieval, I am often forced to create "local" system object that are equal to CommLib objects. I use Converter Utility class to convert from such objects to CommLib objects.

The code might look like this:

```
public static CommLibObjX objXToCommLib(objX p) {
    CommLibObjX b = new CommLibObjX();
    b.setAddressName(p.getAddressName());
    b.setCityId(p.getCityId());
    b.setCountryId(p.getCountryId());
    b.setFieldx(p.getFieldx());
    b.setFieldy(p.getFieldy());
            [...]


    return b;
}
```

Is there a way to generate such code automatically? Using Eclipse or other tools? Some field might have a different name, but I would like to generate a Converter method draft and edit it manually.

Answer (score 2):

try Apache commons-beanutils

```
BeanUtils.copyProperties(p, b);
```

It copies property values from the origin bean to the destination bean for all cases where the property names are the same

Answer (score 1):

If you feel the need to have source code automatically generated, you are probably doing something wrong. I think you need to reexamine the design of the communication between your two "systems". How do these "systems" communicate?

- If they are on different computers or in different processes, design a wire protocol for them to use, rather than serializing objects.
- If they are classes used together, design better entity classes, which are suitable for them both.

Comment: I agree with you in most of the cases, but take the example of DAO and DTO.... people are happy to have converters sometimes.